# PHP: reading config.ini to array with file()

Tags: php, file, ini

My config file looks like this:

```
title = myTitle;
otherTitle = myOtherTitle;
```

when I read the file with file(), it creates this array

```
[0] => title = myTitle;
[1] => otherTitle = myOtherTitle;
```

and what I want the array to look like is

```
[title] => myTitle;
[otherTitle] => myOtherTitle;
```

Am I using the wrong approach her? Should i just read the entire config into a sting and explode it from there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function. It's available in PHP 4 and 5.

If your config file looks like this:

```
one = 1;
five = 5;
animal = BIRD;
```

The function will return the following associative array:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [five] => 5
    [animal] => BIRD
)
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. I knew I had done it before.

Answer (score 0):

I would just loop through the file and explode each line individually.  Here's a simple example, after which you'll end up with `$config` holding all of your data as requested.

```
$config = array();
$lines = file("config.ini");
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $vals = explode('=', $line, 2);
    $config[trim($vals[0])] = trim($vals[1]);
}
```