# How to read config.ini variables in a config.php file

Tags: php, mysql, config, ini

So I correct have a script that uses a config.ini for connecting to the database and with other options, but I have a script that I created which is a config.php and uses the same database. There are variables (database host/username/password) that I would like to pull from the config.ini file and read them inside of the config.php. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: reading config.ini to array with file()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020194/php-reading-config-ini-to-array-with-file)

Comment: It's not a duplucate, because I am trying to do the following:
`Config.ini -> database.params.host = localhost`
and i want to read inside of the php file:
`Config.php -> database.host = $variable from config.ini`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly how and when your app connects to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question & later comments I think that you could be wanting to read an ini file from within two php scripts.  There is nothing stopping you doing this, it would be possible to read the file from within both scripts, but we do not want to repeat the code in each script.

So I would suggest you need three scripts, something along these lines:

```
database.php   // the original which is currently reading from config.ini
config.php     // the new script which you also want to read the config.ini
readconfig.php // does the reading of the ini
```

The `readconfig.php` should have a public function that does something like:

```
public function ReadDbSettings($inifile, $host, $user, $password)
{
       // do the mechanics of reading the ini, use your existing code which is working

       // set the supplied parameters which values from the ini
       $host = $ini_array['HOST'];
       ...

       return TRUE;  // the settings were read
}
```

In terms of the actual mechanics of reading the ini one option is to use [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file) to read in the contents into an array.  A contrived example:

```
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file("my.ini");
    if (empty($ini_array['IniSetting']))
    {
        $this->variable = 'defaultvalue';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->variable = $ini_array['IniSetting'];
    }
```

Comment: I still dont see how that is going to read the config.ini files since they are propogated automatically and I wouldn't know before hand...

Comment: Propogated? Sounds like you might need some more context in your question as I am not following what you are referring to.  Perhaps you  could elaborate on your comment above `-> database.params..` inside your question?

Comment: Okay this is how the structure looks like:
`config
--config.ini
--config.php`

.ini
`database.adapter = pdo_mysql
database.utf8 = true
database.params.host = localhost
database.params.username = [[username generated by server]]
database.params.password = [[password generated by server]]
database.params.dbname = [[dbname generated by server]]
`
.php
`$host = [[this is what i want to fill from the ini file]]
$username = [[this is what i want to fill from the ini file]]
$password = [[this is what i want to fill from the ini file]]
$db_name = [[this is what i want to fill from the ini file]]
`

Comment: So in other words what I am saying is, the config.ini's information is filled automatically by the server with all the details (this is what i mean by propagating), but I am trying to read the information of the config.ini inside of the config.php file so that I can connect to the database. 

**NOTE** Server can only write to one or the other, so since there are so many details that need to be written inside of the config.ini, its best just to be able to read them inside of the config.php

Answer (score 1):

Okay after pulling my head out of my *** i was able to figure it out!

This is what my config.php file looks like:
`<?
    $ini_array      = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
    $host           = $ini_array['database.params.host'];
    $username       = $ini_array['database.params.username'];
    $password       = $ini_array['database.params.password'];
    $db_name        = $ini_array['database.params.dbname'];
    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name) or die('Could not connect to MySQL');
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ('could not open db'.mysql_error());
    ?>`

and it connects fantastically!